# How to search for meta_query LIKE or tax_query LIKE and grab these posts on search results?

Tags: wp-query, search, meta-query, tax-query

I need to search `property` post types, in a regular WP_Query that is not the main query, but I need to be able to search for a value `LIKE` in any of the following meta_queries and also need to search `LIKE` in tax_queries, but the comparison between tax_query and meta_query should NOT be an `AND`, it needs to be an `OR`. How to do this?  Here is how my WP_Query args are setup, but it doesn't return any results where it should:

```
array (
  'post_type' => 'property',
  'posts_per_page' => 10,
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'tax_query' => 
  array (
    'relation' => 'OR',
    0 => 
    array (
      'taxonomy' => 'type',
      'field' => 'name',
      'terms' => 'Strip',
    ),
  ),
  'meta_query' => 
  array (
    'relation' => 'OR',
    0 => 
    array (
      'key' => 'city',
      'value' => 'Strip',
      'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'key' => 'state',
      'value' => 'Strip',
      'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'key' => 'salelease',
      'value' => 'Strip',
      'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      'key' => 'zip',
      'value' => 'Strip',
      'compare' => 'LIKE',
    ),
  ),
)
```

`Strip` is the search term being sent to the `value`.  I have a `type` with a name of `Strip Centers`, but I get empty result here.  I think this is using AND to compare the Type with all of the meta_queries also.  I just want any value of type `OR` any value of the meta_queries.

How to do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at WP_Tax_Query and WP_Meta_Query used by Wp_Query, they return their respective where clauses with an AND relation, and no hook or $args to change that behavior.

Furthermore, the tax_query is computed before the rest of the main query so that it's included in the main query in `term_taxonomy_id IN (...)` form. Also the WP_Tax_Query doesn't accept a LIKE operator ([see doc](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_tax_query/__construct/))

You can see the final query in `WP_Query->request`

```sql
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts  
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )
WHERE 1=1
    AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (1))
    AND (  ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'city' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%Strip%' ) 
        OR  ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'state' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%Strip%' ) 
        OR  ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'salelease' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%Strip%' ) 
        OR ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'zip' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value LIKE '%Strip%' ) ) 
    AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
    AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'))
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

The solution for your issue is to do your own request with `$wpdb` to get all posts ID that match your search value and then convert it to WP_Post objects array.

```php
function search_posts($value)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $value = '%'.$wpdb->esc_like($value).'%';
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT p.ID
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts p
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta m ON m.post_id = p.ID
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships r ON r.object_id = p.ID
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy tt ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = r.term_taxonomy_id AND tt.taxonomy = 'type'
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}terms t ON t.term_id = tt.term_id
        WHERE p.post_status = 'publish' AND p.post_type = 'property'
            AND ((m.meta_key = 'city' AND m.meta_value LIKE %s) 
                OR (m.meta_key = 'state' AND m.meta_value LIKE %s) 
                OR (m.meta_key = 'salelease' AND m.meta_value LIKE %s) 
                OR (m.meta_key = 'zip' AND m.meta_value LIKE %s)
                OR (t.name LIKE %s))
        GROUP BY p.ID", $value, $value, $value, $value, $value);
    $ids = $wpdb->get_col($sql);
    if (is_array($ids) && count($ids) > 0)
        return array_map('get_post', $ids);
    else
        return []; // or whatever you like
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the only way to do it right.  The `post_clauses` filter is a total mess, and was trying with no luck to get taxonomy and meta working together somehow in there.  could only really get the meta keys working nicely, but the taxonomy name is much more involved.

Comment: I suppose an INNER JOIN on the postmeta table is probably more optimized, and shouldn't hurt any, since all posts have postmeta.

Comment: INNER JOIN is better if you are SURE meta exists. If not the query will return nothing, even if a term matches the search string.