# Extend search query to search meta keys values based on search string

Tags: wp-query, custom-field, post-meta, search

I want to create an autocomplete AJAX search and I'm trying to have it where when the user starts typing, the list populates titles matching that search string.

My issue is in the [WP_query](https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/meta_query.html#multiple-meta-keys), because I want to search the title, content and search meta key values and show the results.  I will be searching the `rfi_antenna_sku` meta key and `alive_antenna_sku` meta key, etc for the `product` post type.

My Query:

```
// the ajax function
add_action('wp_ajax_data_fetch' , 'data_fetch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_data_fetch','data_fetch');
function data_fetch(){

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        's' => esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] ),
        'post_type' => array('product'), 
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => 'rfi_antenna_sku',
                'value' => esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] ),
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'alive_antenna_sku',
                'value' => esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] ),
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            )
        )
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
        echo '<ul>';
        while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post(); ?>

            <li><a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></li>

        <?php endwhile;
       echo '</ul>';
        wp_reset_postdata();  
    endif;

    die();
}
```

In case it helps future people, here's the rest:

```
function antennas_competitive_search_form() {
 $output = '<div class="search_bar">';
    $output .= '<form action="/" method="get" autocomplete="off">';
        $output .= '<input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Search Code..." id="keyword" class="input_search" onkeyup="fetch()">';
        $output .= '<button>';
            $output .= 'Search';
        $output .= '</button>';
    $output .= '</form>';
    $output .= '<div class="search_result" id="datafetch">';
        $output .= '<ul>';
            $output .= '<li>Please wait..</li>';
        $output .= '</ul>';
    $output .= '</div>';
 $output .= '</div>';

 return $output;
}


/**
 * Ajax Search
 */
// add the ajax fetch js
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'ajax_fetch' );
function ajax_fetch() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fetch(){

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
        type: 'post',
        data: { action: 'data_fetch', keyword: jQuery('#keyword').val() },
        success: function(data) {
            jQuery('#datafetch').html( data );
        }
    });

}
</script>

<?php
}
```

And lastly, the links I've researched before posting here:

[WP_Query with meta_value LIKE 'something%'](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/193356/wp-query-with-meta-value-like-something)

[Get posts by meta value](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/144078/get-posts-by-meta-value)

[How to search for meta_query LIKE or tax_query LIKE and grab these posts on search results?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/284221/how-to-search-for-meta-query-like-or-tax-query-like-and-grab-these-posts-on-sear?rq=1)

[Using meta query ('meta_query') with a search query ('s')](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78649/using-meta-query-meta-query-with-a-search-query-s?answertab=scoredesc#tab-top)

Comment: The [last link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/78649) have various options/code that you can choose from, so have you tried any of that? Or what have you tried and what didn't work as expected? Do you want the meta query to be used only if a search keyword is specified, i.e. "no search, no meta query"?

Comment: I saw that, and I did try this answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/208939/20663 but it still didn't work.  When I tried typing any of the values I had stored as a value in one of the custom fields it didn't pull up and response data was empty.

Comment: I wrote an [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/401642/137402) to a similar question in January 2022, so you can use the same trick/workaround there, but in your case, you don't need to hook on `pre_get_posts` and simply add `'_search_OR' => true` to your `$args` array. Another option is of course to manually construct your `( <search query> OR <meta query> )` *during the `posts_search` hook*, but you will need to handle matters such as table joining and aliasing, and writing the SQL which searches in your metadata, on your own.

Comment: Also, you should instead set the `posts_per_page` to a reasonable high number which the database can handle at a time, e.g. `100` or `50`, and if there are more posts, then use the `paged` arg to paginate your query. You should also ensure that `$_POST['keyword']` is *not empty or has a non-zero length* before adding your meta query.. and use `wp_die()` instead of `die()`. You should also use `get_permalink()` instead of [`post_permalink()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/post_permalink/) which has long been deprecated.